# how to change visibility edittext in mainactivity from alertdialog

Tags: android, android-edittext, android-alertdialog, visibility, android-inflate

I have designed an alertdialog of which when the user press the save button

**MainActivity**

```
public void openDialog(View view) {
    RegDialog regDialog = new RegDialog();
    regDialog.show(getSupportFragmentManager(), "Register Dialog");
}
```

and I have `editText` in `MainActivity` ,I want to change visibility for editText when press `onClick` in `.setPositiveButton`

**AlertDialog**

```
public Dialog onCreateDialog(@Nullable Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    AlertDialog.Builder builder = new AlertDialog.Builder(getActivity());

    LayoutInflater inflater = getActivity().getLayoutInflater();
    View view = inflater.inflate(R.layout.layout_reg_dialog, null);

    builder.setView(view)
            .setTitle("Titel")
            .setPositiveButton("Activer", new DialogInterface.OnClickListener() {
                @Override
                public void onClick(DialogInterface dialog, int which) {
                    //change visiblity editText
                }
            });
```

Comment: get your ET via `view.findViewById(R.id.edit_text);`

Answer (score 0, accepted):

In the same way you can call `getActivity().getLayoutInflater()`, you can call `getActivity().findViewById()`:

```
@Override
public void onClick(DialogInterface dialog, int which) {
    EditText et = getActivity().findViewById(R.id.your_id_here);
    et.setVisibility(View.GONE);
}
```